# Partial serialization of model based on property attribute

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I am looking for a way to partially serialize a model to Json using [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json). How the partial serialization should look like I want to define on the property of a parent object. So partial serialization can look different for different parent models. To illustrate what I want here some code:

```
private class MyTestObject
{
    [SerializeOnly("TestValue1")]
    [SerializeOnly("TestValue3")]
    public ComplexTestObject Property1 { get; set; }

    public MyTestObject()
    {
       Property1 = new ComplexTestObject();
    }
}

private class ComplexTestObject
{
    public string TestValue1 { get; set; }
    public string TestValue2 { get; set; }
    public string TestValue3 { get; set; }
    public ComplexTestObject()
    {
        TestValue1 = "value1";
        TestValue2 = "value2";
        TestValue3 = "value3";
    }
}
```

Now when I serialize an instance of class `MyTestObject` I want to get the following Json:

```
{
    "Property1" : {
        "TestValue1" : "value1",
        "TestValue3" : "value3",
    }
}
```

You can see that `SerializeOnly` is used to define which properties are to be serialized.

To achieve this I can create a `SerializeOnlyAttribute`. When trying to use this in a custom Serialization ContractResolver I can only see the attributes of the specific member and so I cannot see any `SerializeOnlyAttribute` because they reside on the parent.

Is there a simple way to achieve the desired behavior with Json.Net? It might be possible writing a custom JsonConverter but how can this be built such that only handling the attributes is covered and still the default converters are used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this in two parts:

- Create a custom JsonConverter that can accept a list of names of properties to serialize.
- Create a custom ContractResolver that looks for properties that have at least one `[SerializeOnly]` attribute applied, and apply the custom converter to those properties, passing the list of child property names gathered from the applied attributes.

Here is what the resolver might look like:

```
class CustomResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        IList<JsonProperty> props = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);
        foreach (JsonProperty prop in props)
        {
            if (!prop.PropertyType.IsPrimitive && prop.PropertyType != typeof(string))
            {
                PropertyInfo pi = type.GetProperty(prop.UnderlyingName);
                if (pi != null && pi.CanRead)
                {
                    var childPropertiesToSerialize = pi.GetCustomAttributes<SerializeOnly>()
                                                       .Select(att => att.PropertyName);
                    if (childPropertiesToSerialize.Any())
                    {
                        prop.Converter = new CustomConverter(childPropertiesToSerialize);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return props;
    }
}
```

And here is the converter:

```
class CustomConverter : JsonConverter
{
    private HashSet<string> propertiesToSerialize;

    public CustomConverter(IEnumerable<string> propertiesToSerialize)
    {
        this.propertiesToSerialize = new HashSet<string>(propertiesToSerialize);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in value.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if (prop.CanRead && propertiesToSerialize.Contains(prop.Name))
            {
                writer.WritePropertyName(prop.Name);
                serializer.Serialize(writer, prop.GetValue(value));
            }
        }
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Demo:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var test = new MyTestObject();
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        settings.ContractResolver = new CustomResolver();
        settings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test, settings);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }

    class MyTestObject
    {
        [SerializeOnly("TestValue1")]
        [SerializeOnly("TestValue3")]
        public ComplexTestObject Property1 { get; set; }

        [SerializeOnly("TestValue2")]
        public ComplexTestObject Property2 { get; set; }

        public MyTestObject()
        {
            Property1 = new ComplexTestObject();
            Property2 = new ComplexTestObject();
        }
    }

    class ComplexTestObject
    {
        public string TestValue1 { get; set; }
        public string TestValue2 { get; set; }
        public string TestValue3 { get; set; }
        public ComplexTestObject()
        {
            TestValue1 = "value1";
            TestValue2 = "value2";
            TestValue3 = "value3";
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "Property1": {
    "TestValue1": "value1",
    "TestValue3": "value3"
  },
  "Property2": {
    "TestValue2": "value2"
  }
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Fj7QcW

Comment: Awesome! I like this solution! Thx :-)

Comment: No problem; glad I could help.

Answer (score -1):

C# already has an attribute to help you with this

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.scriptignoreattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

```
[ScriptIgnore]
public string MyParam{get;set;}
```

Comment: At first in Json.Net this would be [JsonIgnore]. And second then the complete property is not serialized but I want to partially serialize it. And I want to define the behavior on the parent!